# Hashtable scrambling?

Tags: c#, hashtable

I have the following hashtable on my application:

```
System.Collections.Hashtable colunas = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
colunas.Add("Nome", "Nome");
colunas.Add("Departamento", "Departamento");
colunas.Add("Cargo", "Cargo");
```

After, I pass this hashtable as parameter to a function and when I pass through the hashtable in a foreach I get the following results:

```
Departamento
Nome 
Cargo
```

**Why the result is in that order and not in this:**

```
Nome
Departamento
Cargo
```

**-- EDIT --**

Ok, I understood the reason, but what can I use instead of hashtable to preserve the insertion order?

Comment: You should never use `System.Collections`.  Instead, use `System.Collections.Generic`.

Comment: Because they aren't type-safe.

Comment: They are type-safe alright. They just need some ugly boxing and casting.

Comment: They're not statically typed.

Comment: @WellingtonZanelli - what do you want to do with the resulting list?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. You could use `var colunas = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();`. Or maybe what you want is really `var colunas = new Item()` where `Item` is a type declared by `class Item { public string Nome { get; set; } public string Departamento { get; set; } public string Cargo { get; set; } }`.

Comment: If the keys and values are the same why are you using a dictionary? Why not just a list?

Comment: @EricLippert the values can be different, just in the example they are equal.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I used your suggestion of using `var colunas = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();` and it worked for my problem. Please, post it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is "promoted" from a comment, by request from the Original Poster.

If it is important for you to keep the order of insertion, you might want to simply use a `List<>` whose elements are somehow pairs of strings. Two solutions are natural, either:

```
var colunas = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
colunas.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Nome", "Nome"));
colunas.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Departamento", "Departamento"));
colunas.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Cargo", "Cargo"));
```

or:

```
var colunas = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
colunas.Add(Tuple.Create("Nome", "Nome"));
colunas.Add(Tuple.Create("Departamento", "Departamento"));
colunas.Add(Tuple.Create("Cargo", "Cargo"));
```

There's a technical difference between `KeyValuePair<,>` and `Tuple<,>` because the former is a `struct` (value type) and the latter is a `class` (reference type), but since both `KeyValuePair<,>` and `Tuple<,>` are ***immutable*** types, that is probably unimportant. Then decide if the property names `Key`/`Value` or `Item1`/`Item2` are best suited for your use.

Note that if you use this solution, you don't get the benefits a hashtable offers. You don't get fast lookup on key. And there's no guarantee that the `List<>` can't have many entries with the same "key" string (first component of the pair). That string could even be `null`.

***If*** you want to sort the `List<>` after all, at some point, the call `colunas.Sort();` (no comparer argument given) will work for `Tuple<,>` (lexicographic order) but not for `KeyValuePair<,>`. Of course if you wanted the collection sorted *all the time* by keys, you would use `SortedDictionary<string, string>` as suggested by another answer.

Answer (score 6):

Hashtables do not preserve insertion order.

Instead, they use an unspecified order based on the hashcodes of the keys.

Answer (score 2):

`Hashtable` represents a collection of key/value pairs that are organized based on the hash code of the key.

Answer (score 1):

> but what can I use instead of hashtable to preserve the insertion order?

You have a choice:

- `System.Collections.Generic.SortedList<TKey, TValue>`
- `System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`

See the [remarks section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx) here for the differences.

Comment: But using SortedList or SortedDictionary my result will be always alphabetical ordered, correct? I want to always keep the insertion order.

Comment: That's incompatible with a Dictionary/HashSet. You'll need to store things twice.

Comment: Henk, see his data, he doesn't actually have a key/value relationship here.  He just needs a `List`.